# Applying function to all files in directory using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, gdal-translate, function

I have a problem for apply this function in all files.
This script is about the extraction of the bands from a raster and I want to use it on all the file raster in the folder. It works on the single file but I can not apply to all files from the folder.

Why?

```
import glob, os, processing
from osgeo import gdal
in_path="C:/.../folder_input/"
out_path ="C:/.../folder_output/"

file_list = os.listdir(path)

file_list= [file for file in os.listdir(path) if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.ecw']

for file in file_list:
print (file)

src_ds = gdal.Open(file)

for file in range (1,file.RasterCount+1):
out_ds = gdal.Translate(out_path + '1' + str(file) + 'ecw',src_ds, format='GTiff', bandList=[i])
out_ds=None
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/55020344/820534

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to define a function and make the file(s) in the directory that you're trying to work with an argument.

```
>>> def function_name(files):
#this is where you write what you want your function to do...
out_ds = gdal.Translate(out_path + '1' + str(files) + 'ecw',src_ds, format='GTiff', bandList=[i])
out_ds=None
>>> for file in os.listdir(path): #this will loop through the path and get each file.
function_name(file) #this is where you pass the file to the function.
```

Comment: I tried but it returns AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'. You could explain me better, I'm not practical enough with python and programming..